# jquery date picker doesn't appear

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

jQuery code:

```
 <script src="js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#book').validate({
        rules : {
            name : 'required',
            sdate : {
                required : true,
                date : true
            },
            seats :{
                required : true,
                number : true,
                range:[1,9]
            },
        },// end rules

    }); // end validate()

    $('#sdate').datepicker({
        minDate : new Date("<?php echo $start;?>"), 
        maxDate : new Date("<?php echo $end?;>") 
    });

});
</script>`
```

Value for date is retrieved from the MySQL database and stored in the variable after converting it to date format. Its passed to the date picker - minDate and maxDate. If I manually pass the date to the minDate and maxDate, the datepicker appears, in the above case even the validation doesn't work nor does the datepicker appear.

PHP code:

```
 $st=$value->getStart();
 $start = date("Y-m-d h:i:s", strtotime($st));
 $ed=$value->getEnd();
 $end = date("Y-m-d h:i:s", strtotime($ed));
```

HTML code:

```
Show Date <input name="sdate" type="text" id="sdate" />
```

Any help on this issue is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any errors in developer console?

Comment: Are you calling the UI script?

Comment: The `datepicker` is part of jQuery UI library, not the base jQuery library, and you have not included it in your page.  To use it you need to include the jQuery UI script and CSS in addition to the base jQuery library.

Answer (score 0):

Time in format `Y-m-d h:i:s` will not with javascript's Date object. Try to use for example this format: `D M d Y H:i:s O`

```
 $st=$value->getStart();
 $start = date("D M d Y H:i:s O", strtotime($st));
 $ed=$value->getEnd();
 $end = date("D M d Y H:i:s O", strtotime($ed));
```

Comment: And in the source code of the page dates are formated well? Does the picker appear or only not showing the limits? Does developer console prints something?

Comment: I'm actually very new to PHP. I tried the above format for the dates. The datepicker doesn't appear. I'm not sure where to find the developer console. I'm using Eclipse.

Comment: Open your webpage in your browser and press Control-Shift-J (Chrome/Firefox). If datepicker doesn't appear at all, you have probably javascript error in your page. Maybe send us a link.

Comment: I fixed it by changing the format of date used by date picker.